# convert Dictionary<String, double> to Dictionary<String, float> using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I can do the conversion with the for loop, but is there a Linq statement that I can use as a one-liner?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
var newdict = original.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (float)kvp.Value);
```